# When does $\sum_l p(e|l)p(l|s)=p(e|s) $ holds?

Tags: probability, proof-writing

I'm working with Bayesian Networks and conditional probability.
Let $e$, $l$ and $s$ be random variables, the expression
$$\sum_l  p(e|l)p(l|s)=p(e|s) $$

holds always? If so, how can I derive it using the definition of conditional probability and marginalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, $s$ is the parent of $l$ and $l$ is the parent of $e$ in the Bayesian network. Therefore,
$$
p(e \mid l, s) = p(e \mid l)
$$
since the probability of $e$ depends only on $l$. Then
\begin{align}
\sum_l p(e\mid l)p(l\mid s) = \sum_l p(e\mid l, s)p(l\mid s) = \sum_l p(e, l \mid s) = p(e \mid s)
\end{align}
where the second equality is due to
$$
p(A, B \mid C) = p(A \mid B, C) \cdot p(B \mid C)
$$
and the last equality is due to the law of total probability.

Comment: That is one situation.  More generally, the equality, $p(e\mid \ell, s)=p(e\mid \ell)$, means that $e$ and $s$ are conditionally independent when given $\ell$, and *vice versa*.

$$\begin{align}p(e\mid s)~&= \sum_\ell p(e,\ell\mid s) && \text{Law of Total Probability}\\[1ex] &=~\sum_\ell p(e\mid\ell,s)~p(\ell\mid s) &&\text{Definition of Conditional Probability}\\[1ex] &=~\sum_\ell p(e\mid \ell)~p(\ell\mid s) && e\perp s\mid\ell\end{align}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Good point.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks fo the comment, but I don't see any difference with the answer. The first equation of the answer $p(e|l,s)=p(e|l)$ means that $e$ and $s$ are conditionally independent given $l$.